# QGIS reads blank cells as "nan" instead of "NULL"

Tags: qgis, r, vector-layer, null

I use QGIS to visualise my data but I use R when I have to do many treatments on my attribute tables. (package `terra`)

But when I write vector data with R, the Na's appear in QGIS attribute table as "nan" when it usually writes "NULL" in grey when the cell is blank. The columns remain considered as real though "nan" values are present.

It is a problem since I can't select attributes by the expressions `"field" is null` or `"field" = "nan"`.

I tried to replace them with `if("field" = "nan", NULL, "field")` without success either.

Do you know a way to change these "nan" to NULL? Preferably on the R side.

Comment: I have tried to improve this in `terra`. It now writes NULL to files instead of NaN. Although the behavior may depend on the file format you use; and you do not provide much information. Perhaps you can try the development version (1.5-36) that you can install with: `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't be able to help with sorting this in R, however regarding the post-processing in QGIS, you current request in the field calculator is:

`if("field" = "nan", NULL, "field")`

which you said doesn't work. I would suggest to try either of the two following syntaxes:

`if("field" = 'nan', NULL, "field")`

or

`if("field" = 'nan', "", "field")`

and see if you get any better results.

Comment: `if("field" = 'nan', NULL, "field")` worked, thank you for your response.